# Get list of Azure Active Directory Client Users in provider hosted app SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to get Azure active directory users from provider hosted app with following code:

```
private void bindUsers()
{
    ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication();
    IPagedCollection<IUser> lstUsers = client.Users.ExecuteAsync().Result; // Throws Error
}

public static ActiveDirectoryClient GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication()
        {
            string servicePointUri = _AzureResourceUrl + _AzureAppTenantID;
            Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri);
            ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot,
                async () => await AcquireTokenAsyncForApplication());
            return activeDirectoryClient;
        }
```

But line `IPagedCollection<IUser> lstUsers = client.Users.ExecuteAsync().Result;` throws following error:

> An exception of type 'System.AggregateException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Any Solution?

Comment: can you install the latest version of `Microsoft.Bcl.Async` and check ?  Check this link - [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/)

Comment: I have installed it but still not working.. I have also make `bindUsers()` method async..

Comment: @RonakPatel are you able to get users from Azure Active Directory?